# [ros2] reset_world/reset_simulation fail with URDF

Tags: ros2

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everyone,

First of all I'm not sure if its correct to comment a still not accepted PR, so I'm just leaving this here.
This is about [Port time commands (pause / reset)](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/pull/866) PR.

I want to be able to reset my robot, but I'm not achieving the desired results with neither /reset_world nor /reset_simulation. Images are self explanatory, only the pure gazebo model works as expected, not the urdf.

- In **reset_world** MARA model is not affected.
- In **reset_simulation** MARA loses all joint forces, or something like that.

reset_world

[image: reset_world]

reset_simulation

[image: reset_simulation]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21611/%5Bros2%5D-reset_world/reset_simulation-fail-with-urdf/) by [nzlz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2816/nzlz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 90 on 2019-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Thank you for trying out that pull request!

> Images are self explanatory

Actually, could you describe what are the expected outcomes? You say that "In reset_simulation MARA loses all joint forces", and that's what I would expect. I'm not sure how you're applying forces to the model, but on your plugin, you should override the [Plugin::Reset](http://gazebosim.org/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1ModelPlugin.html#a4c4ba0ffe635d14b93794268bd8e5995) method and make sure your controllers respond accordingly. Another way to check if a reset occurred is to get the current simulation time and detect if it has moved backwards.

---

Also, a side note, the ROS 2 pull request you're testing is only exposing Gazebo functionality which you could also access through the GUI. These are the hotkeys on gzclient:

- `Ctrl + R`: Reset simulation
- `Ctrl + Shift + R`: Reset world

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nzlz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2816/nzlz/) on 2019-01-04**:
The plugin I'm using is probably the failing part. But I really don't know how to proceed or what could be failing. (Reset is not implemented.) I would really appreciate if you can give me some hints : https://github.com/AcutronicRobotics/MARA/blob/master/mara_gazebo_plugins/src/mara_gazebo_joint_plugin.cpp

I have to mention I've seen (2 times only) the robot recover by itself after a long time, and start moving normal again. Really don't know why or how this happened.

**Comment by [nzlz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2816/nzlz/) on 2019-01-04**:
I want to mention also that I don't get any console error. The last message is:
[INFO] [mara_joint_state]: Negative sim time difference detected.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2019-01-04**:
On your plugin, I'd check if `joints_[MARAGazeboPluginRosPrivate::AXIS1]->SetPosition(0, goal_position_axis1_rad, false);` is still being called after reset. seconds_since_last_update is probably negative.

**Comment by [nzlz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2816/nzlz/) on 2019-01-07**:
Thanks!! Removing negative time check + Adding initialization variables to Reset() fixed the issue. reset_simulation is working as expected now.